# Open Pdf file from DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using DownloadManager to download file from server then I am trying to open it via
BroadcastReceiver

Solution works fine on Android 12 but on Android 10 PDFViewer stay blank at few seconds and then return me into application

```
fun Activity.openLink(url: String) {
    val downloadmanager = this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
 
    val fileName = "file.pdf"
 
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
        .setTitle("")
        .setDescription("")
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
    downloadmanager.enqueue(request)
 
    val onComplete: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) {
                val downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0)
                val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
                val cursor = downloadmanager.query(query)
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    this@openLink.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
                    val columnStatusIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
 
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnStatusIndex)) {
                        val columnUriIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)
                        val uriString: String = cursor.getString(columnUriIndex)
                        val urlFixer = uriString.replace ("file://", "")
 
                        val file = File(urlFixer)
 
                        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@openLink, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider", file)
                        val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
                        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
 
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(target, ""))
                        cursor.close()
 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.applicationContext
        .registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.aaa.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
```

file_provider_filepaths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
 
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
 
</paths>
```

Comment: its Just a URI problem.

Comment: Yes. You are using FileProvider (for a file path you tried to obtain in an illegal way) to get an uri. But instead you should use the uri you obtained from DownloadManager itself. So use Uri.parse(uriString);

Comment: Now I got "No apps can perform this action"